Deriving the partition function for the quantum spherical $p$-spin model from first principles
In this paper, the authors start with a Hamiltonian of $N$ bosonic spins with $p$-body interactions, given by the sum over eq. (1.3):
$$
\mathcal{H}=\sum_{i_{1}<\ldots<i_{p}}J_{i_{1}\ldots i_{p}}\sigma_{i_{1}}\ldots\sigma_{i_{p}},
$$
where $i=1,\ldots,N$. The spins are subject to a 'spherical constraint', whereby $\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sigma_{i}\sigma_{i}=N$, and the interaction strengths $J_{i_{1}\ldots i_{p}}$ follow a normalised Gaussian distribution as in eq. (2.2). They then proceed to write down the partition function in Euclidean time $\tau$ at inverse temperature $\beta$ in eq. (2.1):
$$
Z[J_{i_{1}\ldots i_{p}}]=\int D\sigma_{i}\exp\left\{-\int_{0}^{\beta}d\tau\left[\frac{M}{2}\dot{\sigma}_{i}(\tau)\dot{\sigma}_{i}(\tau)+\sum_{i_{1}<\ldots<i_{p}}J_{i_{1}\ldots i_{p}}\sigma_{i_{1}}\ldots\sigma_{i_{p}}\right]\right\}.
$$
I have two questions about this:

Where does the 'kinetic' term in the square brackets come from?
How would one derive this path integral from first principles, i.e. a coherent state approach, with all the usual machinery of a formal limit etc.? Is this even possible?

My hope is that question 2. will answer question 1., but I would appreciate any help nonetheless!

Every good book on quantum mechanics or QFT will explain why a kinetic term appears by deriving it from scratch. See also the Wikipedia entry.

I agree with the previous comment that this requires learning on path integrals in statistical physics. I would however recommend Negele&Orland or an equivalent condensed matter book - to avoid dealing with unnecessary relativistic complications. Also, this is definitely beyond standard QM courses (but routine in QFT or QFT for condensed matter.)
